# apt-get for a package with when "contrib/source/Sources" is not found correctly

Tags: ubuntu, package-management

I tried to install Webmin on Ubuntu by following the instructions on http://www.webmin.com/deb.html. Using the Update Manager GUI I added the repositories and the key

```
deb http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib
deb http://webmin.mirror.somersettechsolutions.co.uk/repository sarge contrib
```

However when I do an:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install webmin
```

I get the error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://download.webmin.com/download/repository/dists/sarge/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'contrib/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://webmin.mirror.somersettechsolutions.co.uk/repository/dists/sarge/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'contrib/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

Looing at the page at the URL I can see:

```
 7029066c27ac6f5ef18d660d5741979a               20 contrib/source/Sources.gz
```

Is the error caused by the fact that the Sources are compressed with gzip or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it working by removing the source repository in `/etc/apt/sources.list` :

```
deb http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib
#deb-src http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib
```